# How can I make a question - answer command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to create a quiz bot in discord but I can't seem to pull it off. I've done a lot of research about this but I wasn't actually able to find a specific answer. I have read the docs as well, but maybe i'm missing something? This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):

    _list = [
        ('question_1') , 
        ('question_2')]

    list1 = random.choice(_list)

    def answer():
        if _list == list1[0]:
            answer == "1"
        else: 
            answer == "2"

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(list1)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message')

    if msg.content == answer:
        await ctx.send("good")
    else:
        await ctx.send("no")
```

This is the kind of concept I want to use in order to ask my questions. The questions come from a specific list and the answer is based on the position of the question. The result is always "no" from the bot. I think i'm using the if statement wrong and I have no idea how to fix this.

Sorry if the answer is supposed to be obvious and I haven't done enough reading, or if this is impossible to pull off. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna update your code and explain what happened.

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):

        _list = [
        'question_1', 
        'question_2']

        list1 = random.choice(_list)

        def answer():
            answer = "-1"
            if _list[0] == list1:
                answer = "1"
            else: 
                answer = "2"
            return answer

        await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send(list1)
        def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=None)

        if msg.content == answer():
            await ctx.send("good")
        else:
            await ctx.send("no")
```

You can try this out now, and look at what I updated especially the if else statements when you are checking whether the item is the first one in the list or not.

You also don't have to put `question_1` and `question_2` inside parentheses in the _list.

Feel free to let me know if there is any other issue or problem.

Comment: First, I wanna point out that in the line `await ctx.send(questions)`, there was a small blunder of mine since it was supposed to be `list1` instead of `questions`. My bad, but that wasn't the problem. I tried your code but the outcome that the bot sent was still always "no". It didn't seem to fix the problem. Thank you for your time though. I would be really glad if you find another solution.

Comment: Hey again @MarioArquette! Thanks for letting me know that. I've fixed it and updated my answer. Let me know if there is anything else :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Wrecker! Your code is working perfectly and the bot is responding correctly now. Thank for all your help <3